# how to get subjects from course using foreign key in django with the help of one to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am working on website having different courses each course have some no of subjects basically i am using one to many relationship i am having problem in getting output in desired way
(assume i have 2 subjects  i.e. cse and mechanical engineering, cse have 2 subjects html and css similarly mech engineering have 2 subjects thermo and fluid mechanics) i want output like this
**CSE**
html
css

**mechanical engineering**
thermo
fluid mechanics
kindly suggest me what is wrong in my code thats why i cant get desired output`

```
def course(request):
courses = Course.objects.prefetch_related('subjects_set')
context = {'courses': courses}
return render(request, 'test.html', context)


def subjects(request, course_id):
subjects = Subjects.objects.filter(course_id=course_id)
return render(request, 'test.html', {'subjects': subjects})
```

this is my view.py

```
{% for course in courses %}
{{course.title}}
{% for subjects in course.subject_set.all %}
    {{subject.title}}
{% endfor %}
<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

this my html file

```
class Course(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='course/', blank=True)
title = models.TextField(blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Subjects(models.Model):
course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='subject/', blank=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

this is my model

`

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass the `subjects` to the template, sinced it iterates over the `courses`.

What you can do is filter the `Course`s in the `def subjects` and then render it with in the `test.html` as well:

```
def subjects(request, course_id):
    courses = Course.objects.prefetch_related('subjects_set').filter(pk=course_id)
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'courses': courses})
```

Comment: @Sumit8Kumar: you render both the views to the same template, hence the template expects a `courses` item passed to the template. We do that by altering the `subjects` view to pass a queryset with *one* `Course` object.

Comment: Can uh tell me something about my html code i think it also have some problem @willem-van-onsem